# MIPS nested function calls

Tags: c, assembly, mips, mips32, nested-function

I'm trying to convert a C Code to MIPS code.

```
int main() {
  int a;
  int b;
  int result = 0;
  if (a != b)
    result = test(a, b);
  else
    result = a + b;
  return result;
}
int test(int a, int b) {
  if (a > b)
    return multiply(a, b)
  else
    return subtract(a, b)
}
int multiply(int a, int b) {
  return a * b;
}
int subtract(int a, int b) {
  return a - b;
}
```

This code contains nested function calls inside test function.
I have put the return address of test function into stack and trying to return the subtracted or multiplied value to the main.

But in my case, my code executes both subtract and multiply functions. 
I'm trying to put my result to s0. After running s0 always shows subtraction of values. If I put multiply result to s1, s1 shows true value.

I think subtract function overrides value at s0. But when case is multiply, why subtract method is called? I have an if/else block, but this part seems to be not working.

Here is my MIPS Code, what am I doing wrong?

```
.data
    numberA: .word 4
    numberB: .word 2
.text
.globl main

    main:
    addi   $s0, $0, 0 # result = 0
    lw   $a0, numberA
    lw   $a1, numberB

    bne $a0, $a1, L1
    add $s0, $a0, $a1
L1: jal test

    add $s0, $v0, $0

    li $v0,10
    syscall 


test:
        addi $sp, $sp, -4
        sw $ra, 0($sp)

        slt $s1,$a1,$a0
        bne $s1, 1, ELSE
        jal multiply
ELSE:   jal subtract

lw $ra, 0($sp)

addi $sp, $sp, 8

jr $ra


subtract:
    sub $s0, $a0, $a1
    jr  $ra


multiply:
    mult $a0, $a1
    mflo $s0
    jr $ra
```

Comment: This isn't a nested function.  That would be `int foo(){  int nested(){ return 1;}   blah blah foo();  blah foo(); }`, where `nested()` can access local variables in `foo`.  GCC supports that: 
 https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Nested-Functions.html.  What you're doing is just making function calls from a function.  That's normal.  Functions that don't make any calls are called leaf functions (they are leaves of the call tree).  So you're really asking how to write non-leaf functions in MIPS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, that after you return from *multiply*, you  *still* call *subtract* in the next line. You have to return from the function *test* after calling *multiply*.
However, since the function calls are both the last instruction of your function, you can use the following shortcut:

```
test:
        slt $s1,$a1,$a0
        bne $s1, 1, ELSE
        j multiply
ELSE:   j subtract
```

This way, you do not have to store the $ra in your stack, but you can directly use it to jump back to the *caller* of *test* in the `jr $ra` of *subtract* and *multiply*. This way it should work as intended.

Alternatively, skip over `jal subtract` after returning from multiply:

```
       jal multiply
       j OUT
ELSE:  jal subtract

 OUT:  ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply  but i have to use stack, because this is my homework :)

Comment: @mekafe Ok, then use the alternative way, the point is: do not jump into subtract after returning from multiply